# How can you disable Skrollr on mobile?

Tags: skrollr

I would like to disable skrollr on a screen that is smaller than 640px for the width. Basically no animations on mobile/tablet. I've tried this https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/350 but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work". It should.

Answer (score 7):

These solutions are all very complicated for completing such a small task. I did some research on this and tried to implement various plugins (as described above) to disable skrollr for mobile, but without any luck. Eventually I thought "why can't I just use a couple of lines of jQuery to solve this instead of relying on various lengthy plugins?" So, I wrote a simple if/then script where I would usually just call for skrollr to initiate, which enables skrollr only when the width size of the browser windows is > 1000px. Quick and dirty.

```
  <script src="src/skrollr.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
          var s = skrollr.init()
      }
    });
  </script>
```

That's it. Work's fine for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty simple and there are multiple ways of achieving this. I use a plugin called enquire which you can download here http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

After downloading the plugin and adding it to your project, write the below code which enables and disables skrollr.

```
( function( $ ) {

    function enableSkrollr(){
        console.log('we are on desktop');

        // Enable Skroll only for non-touch devices
        if(!Modernizr.touch){
            var s = skrollr.init({
                forceHeight: false
            });
        }

    }

    function disableSkrollr(){
        console.log('we are on mobile');

        // Destroy Skrollr
        var s = skrollr.init();
        s.destroy();
    }

    enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 641px)", {
        match : function() {
            enableSkrollr();
        },  
        unmatch : function() {
            disableSkrollr();
        }
    });

} )( jQuery );
```

The above code will only enable skrollr on a screen that is atleast 641px wide. You can change this value as you like. Hope this helps you mate.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like that!

Please note that I have JQUERY and Modernizr on my web page so this is not a plain javascript solution :

```
    var tomCS = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Check the width of the screen
    tomCS.winW = $(window).width();
    // Check if it's a touch screen (based on Modernizr) - Remove if it if you want    
    tomCS.isTouch = false;
    if($('.touch')[0]){
        tomCS.isTouch = true;
    }
    // If the size of the screen is lower or equal to 767, we are on a mobile device
    tomCS.isMobile = false;
    if(tomCS.winW <= 767){
        tomCS.isMobile = true;
    }
    // If we are not on a mobile device, initiate skrollr
    if (!tomCS.isMobile){
        tomCS.s = skrollr.init({forceHeight: true});
    }
});

// Disable or enable skrollr on window resize
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log("RESIZE");
    tomCS.winW = $(window).width();
    if(tomCS.winW <= 767){
        console.log("MOBILE");
        tomCS.isMobile = true;
        if($('.skrollable')[0]){
        tomCS.s.destroy();
        }
    } else {
        console.log("NOT MOBILE");
        if(!$('.skrollable')[0]){
        tomCS.s = skrollr.init({forceHeight: true});
        }
    }
});
```

Cheers,

J.

Comment: This is the only solution that includes resize! Great job!

Answer (score 1):

I've used a a jQuery class called breakpoints.js.

```
$(window).setBreakpoints({
        // use only largest available vs use all available
        distinct: true, 
        // array of widths in pixels where breakpoints
        breakpoints: [
            320,
            480,
            768  
        ] 
    }); 

    $(window).bind('enterBreakpoint320',function() {
        console.log("this is now 320");

        if(s != undefined)
        {
            console.log('destroy');
            s = skrollr.init().destroy();
        }
        console.log(s);
    });

    $(window).bind('enterBreakpoint480',function() {
        console.log("this is now 480");

        if(s != undefined)
        {
            console.log('destroy');
            s = skrollr.init().destroy();
        }
    });

    $(window).bind('enterBreakpoint768',function() {
        console.log("this is now 768");
        s = skrollr.init({
                forceHeight: true
            });
        console.log(s);

    });
```